# laravel/mysql - how to perform search query with 3k list values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm receiving from an external API a list with 3.000 values (car part codes).

Now I'm trying to get from my database all entries that contains one of these codes.

```
$q = Product::query();
$q->where('codigo', '');
foreach($keys as $v){
  $q->orWhere('codfabrica', $v);                 // varchar 191
  $q->orWhere('gtin', $v);                       // varchar 191
  $q->orWhere('codoriginal', $v);                // varchar 191
  $q->orWhere('codreferencia', $v);              // varchar 191
  $q->orWhere('aplicacao', 'LIKE', '%'.$v.'%');  // medium text
}
$found = $q->get();
```

This is taking 10 minutes but it works.

How can I speed up or optimize this query?

Comment: I think it's better to use a WHERE IN clause to search for multiple values at once instead of using multiple OR conditions. If you're unsure how to do it, let me know, and I can provide you with an example.

Comment: and also,If your `Product` model has relationships with other models, you can use eager loading to retrieve the related data at the same time as the products.this approach can reduce the number of database queries and improve the performance.

Comment: @Freeman worked like a charm for varchar fields., however mediumText field can't be used whereIn()

Comment: Any LIKE statement is going to hurt performance, as that amounts to a full-text search for the column, especially if it's not indexed.

Comment: Multiple `'LIKE', '%'.$v.'%'`  may be replaceable with a single `'REGEXP', implode('|', $keys)` so it at least only reads the text column once per row. (Note this will probably not be portable to other DBMS)

Comment: you can `CAST` to varchar if the length allows.

Comment: Maybe you are missing indexes? Can you share the execution plan for that query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try chunking the list into smaller subsets and perform multiple queries.

```php
$chunkSize = 100;
$keysChunks = array_chunk($keys, $chunkSize);

$found = collect();

foreach ($keysChunks as $chunk) {
    $q = Product::query();
    $q->where('codigo', '');

    $q->whereIn('codfabrica', $chunk)
        ->orWhereIn('gtin', $chunk)
        ->orWhereIn('codoriginal', $chunk)
        ->orWhereIn('codreferencia', $chunk)
        ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($chunk) {
            foreach ($chunk as $v) {
                $query->orWhere('aplicacao', 'LIKE', '%' . $v . '%');
            }
        });

    $found = $found->concat($q->get());
}

$found = $found->unique();
```

Answer (score 1):

To speed up this I guess you can make an array of the values you are getting from API and check with the whereIn query.